# Calculate skewness per group for columns

Tags: r

I have a file with daily data for multiple years. I would like to calculate the **skewness** **for every month** for a variable. I have multiple files as data.frame. I guess a similar question might have been answered before - the answer must lie somewhere in the **moments** or **e1071** package, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Is there a skewness function in R than can help me that is similar to one of the formulas for mean and standard deviation below?:

```
 # take average of a column per month
 MEAN1 <- ddply(FILENAME, c("Month"), function(x) colMeans(x[c("variable1",   "variable2")]))

 #take standard deviation of all columns per month
 sd1 <- ddply(FILENAME, .(Month), colwise(sd)) 
#whereafter I delete the non-relevant columns
```

I would like the final result to be something like:

```
month variable1skewness
01 1.5
02 2.1
03 2.4
04 2.2
05 2.6
06 1.8
07 3.3
08 4.1
09 3.4
10 3.2
11 4.1
12 1.9
```

All help is appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Could you please give a reproducible example (i.e. use built-in or publicly available data)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The `tidy.data.frame` method in `broom` will calculate skewness, kurtosis, and a bunch of other values.

Look at, for example

```
library(broom)
tidy(mtcars)
```

Not having a reproducible example, I've had to fudge an example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

split(mtcars[, c("mpg", "gear")], mtcars$gear) %>%
  lapply(function(x) cbind(gear = x$gear[1], tidy(x))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  filter(column == "mpg") %>%
  select(gear, column, mean, sd, skew, kurtosis)
```

There is probably a cleaner way to do it with `dplyr::do`, but I'm not that clever.